# Why can't I destroy() these waypoints?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

The site I'm working on is using jquery waypoints version 3.1.1. I can destroy a waypoint from within it's handler like so:

```
var foo = $('#myElem').waypoint({
    handler: function() {
        // do something
        this.destroy();
    },
    offset: 'bottom-in-view'
});
```

but not like this:

```
foo.destroy();
```

I get the error:

```
foo.destroy is not a function
```

I also can't destroy it from a context basis:

```
var ctx = Waypoint.Context.findByElement($('#myElem'));
ctx.destroy();
```

I get the error:

```
Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined
```

The only way I can destroy a waypoint is from within the handler or using destroyAll:

```
Waypoint.destroyAll();
```

but I can't use destroyAll as there are other wyapoints on the page that I don't want destroyed. Ideally I can do it on a per waypoint basis like so:

```
foo.destroy();
```

or at the very least on a context basis. What's the issue here, I'm following the docs but not getting the expected results. Perhaps because I'm using an older version?

Comment: did you remove `this.destroy()` from the handler prior to calling `foo.destory()`, etc.?

Comment: @RobM. in many cases the waypoints haven't been fired when I try to destroy them so the handler code never executes. Still I tried removing `this.destroy()` from within the handler just now and same `foo.destroy is not a function` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*foo* is an array, so you would need to write:

```
foo[0].destroy();
```

Also consider this from [imakewebthings.com/waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/guides/jquery-zepto/):

> There is one major difference between using the `$.fn.waypoint` method with versions 2.0 and 3.0. In 2.0, the same jQuery object was returned for chaining purposes, as is common among core jQuery methods. In 3.0, an array of `Waypoint` instances is returned.

Comment: haha oh man, thank you. This silly thing caused me much grief.

Comment: Another tidbit: `var ctx = Waypoint.Context.findByElement($('#myElem'));` would return undefined because you passed it a jQuery object, but it expects a regular HTMLElement. `$('#myElem')[0]` would have given you the right parameter.